# Dual of free Hopf algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose I have a finite or countable alphabet $X$ of non-commutative indeterminates (letters) and I consider the free polynomial ${\bf Q}$-algebra ${\bf Q}\langle X\rangle$ as a Hopf algebra $H$ by equipping it with the coproduct $\Delta(x)=x\otimes 1+1\otimes x$ for every $x\in X$. Let $L$ be the Lie algebra of elements in $H$ that are primitive for $\Delta$, and let $B$ denote a set of elements forming a linear basis for $L$. Then the dual Hopf algebra $H^\vee$ is isomorphic to $H$ as a vector space. Let $\phi:H\rightarrow H^\vee$ denote that isomorphism, which just maps monomials in letters of $X$ to their dual monomials. As a Hopf algebra $H^\vee$ is equipped with the commutative shuffle multiplication. The space $H^\vee$ mod constants and non-trivial products is the Lie coalgebra $L^\vee$, so $\phi(B)$ forms a set of multiplicative generators for the ${\bf Q}$-algebra $H^\vee$. My question is whether these elements generate freely, i.e. whether $H^\vee$ is a free commutative algebra on the elements $\phi(B)$, and is this even a well-known result, possibly even in Bourbaki.